# Difference in Postgis and QIGS Length Calculation?

Tags: gis, open-source, geospatial, postgis, qgis

I am just starting to learn PostgreSQL and PostGIS in particular and I try to follow the Penn State University Intro into Spatial Database Management when I decided to play around a little with the basic data I got. After calculating the length for some LINESTRING data I wanted to check the results using QGIS and thats where the fun started.

Here you can find the SQL Statements I followed and altered a little bit.

https://www.e-education.psu.edu/spatialdb/node/1960

When comparing the results in the attribute table I was confused because the results differed using the ST_Length vs. QGIS Field Calculator´s $Length function despite specifying the same SRID (2163).

```
INSERT INTO lines (name, geom)
VALUES ('Holland Tunnel',ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(
-74.036486 40.730121,
-74.03125 40.72882,
-74.011123 40.725958)',4269)),
('Lincoln Tunnel',ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(
-74.019921 40.767119,
-74.002841 40.759773)',4269)),
('Brooklyn Bridge',ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(
-73.99945 40.708231,
-73.9937 40.703676)',4269));



UPDATE TABLE lines SET laenge = ST_Length(ST_Transform(geom, 2163));
```

The Results are:

Order:

A. ST_Length for Holland Tunnel; Lincoln Tunnel; Brooklyn Bridge

B. $Length for Holland Tunnel; Lincoln Tunnel; Brooklyn Bridge

```
A. 2160,344849130080092; 1631,543481596899937; 694,591179476468028
B. 2195,119177785873489; 1656,890881978494235; 701,411239204245931
```

If I made an obvious mistake I´m really sorry but the suggestions within StackOverflow didn´t point me to the right direction scince they were on the subject of distances based on routing which doesn´t apply here right?

Best regards and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

using:

```
UPDATE lines SET laenge = ST_Length(geom::geography);
```

I can reproduce the Qgis results you posted, that means Qgis is not using the projection you specified to compute the length of the lines

You can read more in qgis about $length:

> The length calculated by this function respects both the current
>   project's ellipsoid setting and distance unit settings. For example,
>   if an ellipsoid has been set for the project then the calculated
>   length will be ellipsoidal, and if no ellipsoid is set then the
>   calculated length will be planimetric.

and about the difference between geometry and geography in:
[postgis docs](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html)

Comment: Thank you @Bruno Carballo i'll try this as soon as im at home